# How Approximate is Electrostatics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Throughout High school, when we learnt electrostatics, we used the conservation of energy using the equation for potential:$$V=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$$for solving questions where 2 isolated opposite charges initially at rest are allowed to move under mutual attraction. If we had to find velocity at some separation $r$ we would do something like this:$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{q_1 q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}(\frac{1}{r_1}-\frac{1}{r_2})$$

But only after learning electromagnetic induction, that it struck me that we have failed to consider that the charges accelerate and hence will produce an electromagnetic field. Which in turn exerts a force on the charges.

Is is alright to just ignore the extra forces that tend to act?
How much is electrostatics valid?

Comment: It's called electro*statics* because we assume the particles are moving so slowly that any magnetic effects are negligible. Have you tried to do the math to see how much difference it makes to consider the magnetic effect in your example?

Comment: @ThePhoton I think "how much difference it makes to consider the magnetic effect in your example" is exactly what the question is asking for. The OP may not know how to do this.

Comment: as I stated in my question, I came across a lot of questions in Fundamentals of Physics, David Halliday, Robert Resnick, and Jearl Walker where charges of 1C magnitude were allowed to move towards or away under mutual interactions. No external forces come to play

Comment: The magnetic forces are generally neglected. The constant involved in magnetic force $\mu$ has very small value of the order $10^{-11}$ as compared to that in electro statics $10^9$

Comment: I think electrostatics should be accurate to order $v^2/c^2$. The magnetic field is proportional to the velocity, and the magnetic force is proportional to the velocity.

Comment: Once the particles accelerate they will radiate.  This realization is what led to the breakdown of the classical model of the H atom in early QM.  An interesting problem.  Look at the Lorentz force for moving charges and try to figure out if there is work done when the charge travels through a B field.  If not then perhaps it does not come into play.

Comment: A standard magnetic field wouldn't do work. But this is an electromagnetic oscillating field...

Comment: @evamPUNdit "electromagnetic oscillating field" is radiation, what the commentby ggcg is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following derivation assumes that at no point in the journey are the charges moving at relativistic speeds: $v\ll c$. It might also be the case that this result appears even with the charges moving at relativistic speeds, but I do not consider that here.

The magnetic field at a point $\vec{r}$ produced by a charge $q$ at a point $\vec{r_0}$ moving with a velocity $\vec{v}$ is

$$\vec{B}(\vec{r})=\frac{\mu_0 q}{4\pi}\frac{\vec{v}\times\hat{r'}}{r'}$$

where $\vec{r'}=\vec{r}-\vec{r_0}$, $r'=|\vec{r'}|$ and

$$\hat{r'}=\frac{\vec{r'}}{r'}$$ The Lorentz force is

$$\vec{F}=q\vec{E}+q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$$

The second term on the right-hand side of the Lorentz force equation is the force exerted by a magnetic field on a charge $q$, and that is what we are interested in. Let us now suppose we have two charged particles, one of charge $q_1$ and the other of charge $q_2$, moving with velocities $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$, respectively. The magnetic force exerted on $q_2$ by the magnetic field produced by $q_1$ is

$$\vec{F}_{1\rightarrow 2}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q_1q_2}{r'^2}\left(\vec{v_2}\times(\vec{v_1}\times\hat{r'})\right)$$

and if you wish to calculate $\vec{F}_{2\rightarrow 1}$ you would simply send $1\rightarrow 2$ and $2\rightarrow 1$, and you would then have have to adjust your $\hat{r'}$. To be precise, $\hat{r'}\rightarrow -\hat{r'}$. In general, these forces do not obey Newton's third law, so they are not equal and opposite and you should calculate both. However, notice that if you start with two charges at rest that move only because of the force that one exerts on the other, then $\hat{r'}$ and $\vec{v_i}$ are collinear: they are attracted or repelled so $\vec{v}$ is along the straight line from one charge to the other, but this is exactly what we have defined $\hat{r'}$ to be. Cross-products of collinear vectors are zero, so the magnetic force produced is zero.

The result is that in this idealized case, there is no need to consider magnetic forces, because they are zero. If you are interested in electrodynamics, you might consider purchasing or borrowing *Introduction to Electrodynamics The Fourth Edition* by David J. Griffiths. This is a standard university textbook for studying electromagnetism. My calculations are based off of the material in this textbook.

Comment: OP may be referring to the radiation reaction force (each particle interacting with the electromagnetic waves generated by itself) rather than the Lorentz force (each particle interacting with the electromagnetic waves generated by the other).

Comment: @J.Murray The result is the same, the electric field produced by itself is collinear with the r' unit vector, so the force is still zero.

Comment: A charged particle with time-varying acceleration will radiate energy and momentum away, and the resulting radiation reaction force will *not* be zero.  It will typically be small, and your assumption of non relativistic motion ultimately justifies neglecting it, but I believe this line of thought is the crux of the question.

Comment: @J.Murray OP just finished highschool. What you're discussing is (at least in my program) graduate level work. That might be beyond the scope of the question, though if they're interested I'd like to see someone else's answer here. However, for most intents and purposes, the above will work. The contributions are negligible at non-relativistic speeds. OP is wondering if we are simply not examining the forces at all and hoping that they do not exist. I've just shown that they are in fact zero.

Comment: @Kraig I think this answer is exactly what I needed. My question actually pertained to em waves and its momentum, since the speeds are non relativistic, its alright to ignore them to a good approximation.